# Error Hola Mundo Spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring, maven

Estoy queriendo hacer mi primer proyecto en `Spring` con `Netbeans` y al momento de de hacer un `Clean and Build` se produce este error:

> Scanning for projects...
>
> -----------------------< com.example:HolaMundo >------------------------
>
> Building HolaMundo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>
> --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
>
> --- maven-clean-plugin:3.3.1:clean (default-clean) @ HolaMundo ---
>
> Deleting C:\Users\dardo\Desktop\HolaMundo\target
>
> --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ HolaMundo ---
>
> Copying 1 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
>
> Copying 0 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
>
> --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ HolaMundo ---
>
> Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
>
> Compiling 1 source file with javac [debug release 8] to target\classes
>
> ---
>
> BUILD FAILURE
>
> ---
>
> Total time:  2.229 s
>
> Finished at: 2023-08-08T20:52:19-03:00
>
> ---
>
> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-> plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project HolaMundo: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]

Comment: Necesitamos que incluyas tus configuraciones de java tanto en maven como en el IDE. Ese error puede producirse (entre otras) por tener diferentes versiones de Java en ambos entornos. Solo con el error es complicado saber exactamente qué está pasando

Comment: el release 8 no existe, normalmente se pone 1.8, y dicha versión como ya es obsoleta lo más probable es que no se incluya. Te recomiendo agregar a tu pregunta tu pom y tu salida del comando `javac -version`

Comment: Agrego mi archivo pom: https://github.com/dardosanchez/pruebaHolaMundo/blob/master/pom.xml                         Y el java - version es este:                                                                                java version "20.0.1" 2023-04-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing) @RuslanLópez